# some columns from sql database not entering php

Tags: php, mysql

I was having some errors with showing my data in the way I wanted, so I tried this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "imaginu2_sec_usr";
$password = "***********";
$dbname = "imaginu2_login";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT title, given, received FROM listings
WHERE id = '5'";
$listingresult = $conn->query($sql);
if ($listingresult->num_rows > 0) {
  while($listingrow = $listingresult->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($listingrow);
  }
}
?>
```

The result I got had blank values, or possibly unreadable characters, listed for the results of the array corresponding to 'given' and 'received'

Columns `given` and `received` for the row with `id=5` both contain `bit(1)` values (0 and 1, respectively) and I can see them within phpmyadmin.

Result I got:

```
array(3) {  ["title"]=> string(14) "Sample Listing" 
            ["given"]=> string(1) "" 
            ["received"]=> string(1) "" 
        }
```

Result I was expecting:

```
array(3) {  ["title"]=> string(14) "Sample Listing" 
            ["given"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["received"]=> string(1) "1" 
        }
```

Comment: Use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()`. It displays more information.

Comment: I got this result: array(3) { ["title"]=> string(14) "Sample Listing" ["given"]=> string(1) "" ["received"]=> string(1) "" } Don't know what it means.

Comment: Can you show the output you're getting, and the output you are expecting, as an edit to the question? You need to format it properly in the question.

Comment: Yes, I've done that now.

Comment: `["given"] => string(1) ""` means "given" is set to a 1 byte char.  Try printing `ord( $listingrow["given"] )`.  This will return the ASCII value as an integer of that first char.  Just to see exactly what it is.

Comment: Did absolutely nothing, both with and without spaces around the variable name.

Comment: Start by showing us your schema for this table

Comment: Take a screenshot of your database table's data please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your column is `BIT(1)`, it will not be a printable character. You will need to make a change, either in columns, or cast/convert the column when selecting. I recommend changing the column unless you *really need* it to be a bit and not an integer.

- **Changing the type** (recommended)
  You should probably change the type of column to `TINYINT(1)` instead - that will be an integer, and not a bit.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE listings MODIFY COLUMN given TINYINT(1);
  ALTER TABLE listings MODIFY COLUMN receivedTINYINT(1);
  ```

If you want to stick with `BIT(1)` for whatever reason, you could give one of the suggestions below a try.

- **Using `ORD()`**

  ```
  SELECT title, ORD(given), ORD(received) FROM listings WHERE id = '5'
  ```
- **Adding zero**
  This will silently typecast it to an integer

  ```
  SELECT title, given+0, received+0 FROM listings WHERE id = '5'
  ```
- **Typecasting by function**
  This will typecast it to an unsigned integer, with the MySQL `CAST()` function

  ```
  SELECT title, CAST(given AS UNSIGNED), CAST(received AS UNSIGNED) FROM listings WHERE id = '5'
  ```
- [MySQL `ORD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_ord)
- [MySQL Cast Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)